# How to generate a HSL or HSI Histogram from a normal Image?

Tags: java, c#, image, histogram, hsl

I am working on a scientific work project, where i need to get some image standards.

To do this, i need a code that generate 3 Histograms from a normal .JPEG .PNG OR .BMP image. The first histogram its the HUE Histogram, the second is SATURATION histogram and the third the LUMINOSITY or INTENSITY histogram.

Im working with HSL and HSI, so the third histogram both LUMINOSITY or INTENSITY would be useful. I would prefer a Java or C# implementation, if theres exists one.

Does anyone knows if theres a project that generete those values from an image?

Thx all;

Answer (score 1):

http://trompelecode.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-create-an-image-histogram-using-csharp-and-wpf/

I think that should be what you are looking for

Comment: Hey, thats kinda 1/3  part what i need. This calculates RGB and Luminosity Histograms, i need Hue, Saturation and Luminosity! But thx anyways :)

Comment: http://trompelecode.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-create-an-image-histogram-using-csharp-and-wpf/HistogramSample.zip does include luminosisty

Comment: Yeah true, just checked that inclues Saturation and Luminosity. Im just looking for a trustable Hue calculation source.